# Why is my axios POST request redirecting to '/?'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am using axios to try and post to MailChimp API. When I click the button that sends the request, the page is redirected to http://localhost:8000/?.

```js
const handleSendEmail = () => {
        
            axios.post('https://{usX}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list-id}/members/', {
                status: 'subscribed',
                email_address: email,
            },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `apikey ${apikey}`,
                    },
                }
            ).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        
    }
```

I am using actual values for the list id, usx and apikey. Here I have just put the names.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript you provided *won't* do that.

Most likely the button you describe is in a form and is submitting that form as well as triggering the JavaScript. Form submissions navigate to new pages.

Use a button button instead of a submit button if you don't want to submit the form.

Comment: Ok great thanks, that fixed the redirecting. But the post request still does not seem to work. It does not seem as if I am getting any response back either